# How to set different gradients to each bar of flot chart?

Tags: javascript, flot

I want to set different gradients to each bar of flot individually, but seems it accepts only solid colors in data object.

```
var data = [{data: [[0,1]], color: "red"},
            {data: [[1,2]], color: "yellow"},
            {data: [[2,3]], color: "green"}];

$.plot("#placeholder",data, {
    series: {
        bars: {
            show: true,
            barWidth: 0.3,
            align: "center",
            lineWidth: 0,
            fill:.75
        }
    },
    xaxis: {
        ticks: [[0,"Red"],[1,"Yellow"],[2,"Green"]]
    }
});
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TPp8m/)

So how can I figure this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `data` object replace the `color: "..."` with something like this:

```
bars: {
  fillColor: {
    colors: ["#ff0000", "#0000ff"]
  }
}
```

The `color` property is mainly for the outline of the bar (which you don't draw because of the `lineWidth: 0` in the options) and will be used as a fallback for the `fillColor` if that is not specified.

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TPp8m/487/